# Fill multiple values comboboxes in ms access form with data from any recordset

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, datatables

I have a table with string typed fields (that is multi-values combobox in table field params).

**Multi-values field settings in table**

[image: Multi-values field settings in table]

I need to autofill new records in form (based on this table) with values of separate recordset from this table.

With usual textfields and comboboxes with single choice it's ok. It works.

**Code for usual textfields and comboboxes**

[image: Code for usual textfields and comboboxes]

How can I autofill multivalues combobox? And how can I detect that control is mutiple values combobox?

Answer (score 0):

I would use "ColumnCount"  for the ctrl has multiple or not.

```
'this is just an example, how to check multi column.
Private Sub Combo1_Click()
 If Me.Combo1.ColumnCount > 1 Then
  MsgBox "Multi"
 Else
  MsgBox "Single"
 End If
End Sub
```

Then use SQL as below  to pull values from the selected values. :)

```
' Get the selected value from the ComboBox
selectedValue = Me.ComboBox1.Value

' Create a SQL query to retrieve all columns for the selected item
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTableOrQuery WHERE IDField = " & selectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, since the value of multi-value field is a recordset itself:

1- It is not possible to detect if the control-source of a combo-box is a multi-value field. It should be done by investigating the field properties of the form's source table.

2- Also, it is not possible to assign a value directly to a multi-value combo-box. It should be done

To check if a table's field is multivalued:

```
Public Function IsMultivalued(ByVal FieldName As String, ByVal TableName As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo NotLookup
    IsMultivalued = CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Fields(FieldName).Properties("AllowMultipleValues")
    Exit Function
NotLookup:
    IsMultivalued = False
End Function
```

It is necessary the table has a primary-key,(e.g. ID) so source and destination records could be identified.

```
Private TableName As String
Private FieldName As String

Private Sub Demo

Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.MoveFirst ' Demo: copy from first record

TableName = Me.RecordSource ' assuming form is bound to a table

Dim rs_values As Recordset ' values stored in the multi-value field

Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Controls
    If ctrl.Tag = "copyFrom" Then
        FieldName = ctrl.ControlSource
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case "textbox"
                ctrl.value = rst(FieldName).value
            Case "combobox"
                If IsMultivalued(FieldName, TableName) Then
                    Clear_Field_Values ' necessary to clear all data before inserting any new value
                   
                    Set rs_values = GetValues(rst("ID"))
                    Do Until rs_values.EOF
                        Insert_Value (rs_values(0))
                        rs_values.MoveNext
                    Loop
                    rs_values.Close
                    Set rs_values = Nothing
                Else
                    ctrl = rst(FieldName).value
                End If
        End Select
    End If
Next

Me.Refresh

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Clearing multivalue field by removing all values from it:

```
Private Sub Clear_Field_Values()
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = Replace("DELETE @TBL.@FLD.value FROM @TBL WHERE ID=@ID", "@TBL", TableName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@FLD", FieldName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@ID", Me.ID)
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

Getting all values of the multivalue field as a recordset:

```
Private Function GetValues(SourceID As Long) As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = Replace("SELECT @FLD.value FROM @TBL WHERE ID=@ID", "@TBL", TableName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@FLD", FieldName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@ID", SourceID)
    Set GetValues = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
End Function
```

Adding new value to the multivalue field:

```
Private Sub Insert_Value(value As Long)
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = Replace("INSERT INTO @TBL (@FLD.value) VALUES (@VLU) WHERE ID=@ID", "@TBL", TableName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@FLD", FieldName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "@ID", Me.ID)
    DoCmd.RunSQL Replace(SQL, "@VLU", value)
End Sub
```